# Getting a " Missing 'itemViewcontainer' " error in a composite view for marionette

Tags: marionette

I have a composite view that is throwing the following error when a model is added to the view's collection: `Uncaught ItemViewContainerMissingError: Missing itemViewContainer`

Here is my compositeView:

```
// VIEW
B.ScrapeUpdate.View = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    // ITEM VIEW
    itemView: B.ScrapeUpdateItem.View,

    // ITEM VIEW CONTAINER
    itemViewContainer: 'tbody',

    // TEMPLATE
    template: Handlebars.compile(templates.find('#scrape-update-template').html()),

    // INITIALIZE
    initialize: function(options){
        _.bindAll(this);

        // Bind events
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.renderCollection);
    }
});
```

I've found that adding the following code in initialize before the binding to collection fixes the bug:

```
    var html = this.renderModel();
    this.$el.html(html);
```

I'm not sure why I need those two lines of code when I have other composite views that work fine. Here is an example of a working composite view:

```
B.BusinessSearchResults.View = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    // ITEM VIEW
    itemView:B.Business.View,

    // ITEM VIEW CONTAINER
    itemViewContainer: 'tbody',

    // TEMPLATE
    template: Handlebars.compile(templates.find('#business-search-results-template').html()),

    // INITIALIZE
    initialize: function(options){
        _.bindAll(this);

        // Bind events
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.renderCollection);

    }
});
```

There seems to be no difference between the views so I'm not sure whats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 // INITIALIZE
    initialize: function(options){
        _.bindAll(this);

        // Bind events
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.renderCollection);
    }
```

these lines of code are not needed. CompositeView does this for you, out of the box. It's likely that the inclusion of this code is causing the problem. Comment out the `this.collection.bind` line and see if you still get the error.